# how to add test phase in aws pipeline that if my API endpoint is healthy then only it is deploy to aws fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, aws-pipeline

here is my buildspec file

version: 0.2

phases:
pre_build:
commands:
- echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
- aws --version
- pwd
- echo $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION and $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID
- ECR_REGISTRY=$(aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION)
- echo "$ECR_REGISTRY" | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
- REPOSITORY_URI=#########################################
- COMMIT_HASH=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
- IMAGE_TAG=build-$(echo $CODEBUILD_BUILD_ID | awk -F":" '{print $2}')

build:
commands:
- echo Build started on `date`
- echo Building the Docker image...
- echo Build started on `date`
- echo Building the Docker image..
- docker login --username ##### --password #######
- docker build -f Dockerfile -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest .
- docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI:latest $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG

post_build:
commands:
- echo Build completed on `date`
- echo Pushing the Docker images...
- docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
- docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
- echo Writing image definitions file...
- printf '[{"###################"}]' $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG > imagedefinitions.json
- cat imagedefinitions.json

artifacts:
files: imagedefinitions.json

i want to do health check for api endpoint. my backend code there in node js.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.